# when i call str.replace() in javascript it goes to error ir is not defined

Tags: javascript, str-replace

See my code

```
for (var i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
            var row_data = allTextLines[i];
            console.log(row_data);
            row_data = row_data.replace(/ /g,'');
            try {

                ir(row_data == "")
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("devicesList").value.length > 0) {
                    document.getElementById("devicesList").value += ",";
                }
                document.getElementById("devicesList").value += row_data;
            }
            catch (oErr) {
                not_read += 1;
                console.log(oErr.message);
                str_error_detail_rows += "<tr><td colspan='2'>Error :" + oErr.message + " could not read line# " + i + " while reading from file.</td></tr>";
            }

        }
```

when i run the code, in the console i got "ir is not defind" please someone help me. the code goes smooth when i remove str.replace. thanks.

Comment: Well that error means that the function `ir()` you're trying to call is not defined. Where is function `ir()`?

Comment: @Pointy It's a misspelling of `if`.

Comment: Don't you mean `if`, not `ir`?

Comment: well, `if !== ir`, if `ir !== function(Boolean)`

Comment: @JLRishe sorry I just woke up :)

Comment: When I remove the replace function it works

Comment: but I want to remove all white spaces and for that i call the replace function and it goes to error

Comment: @SahibZaKhan The error you're seeing has nothing to do with `.replace()`. Please fix your typo and if you're still having a problem after that, we can help.

Comment: Step one in solving an error "[something] is not defined" is to look through your code for [something].

Answer (score 1):

```
ir(row_data == "")
```

should be

```
if(row_data == "")
```

Answer (score -1):

The `ir` should be an `if`, I reckon - it's a typo.

To be perfectly frank, you really could have read through and practically immediately noticed the problem while paying attention.

Comment: It would, but that wasn't there while I was padding out my answer for the minimum character limit.